# Get the duplicate value on DuplicateKeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

In pymongo, when a `DuplicateKeyError` caught, what's the proper way to find out the duplicate value behind the the exception?

Currently I do this

```
try:
    db.coll.insert({key: ['some_value', 'some_value_1']})
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError, e:
    dups = re.findall(r'\{\ +:\ +"(.*)"\ +\}$', e.message)
    if len(dups) == 1:
        print dups[0]
```

It seems to work, but is there any easier way, like

```
try:
    db.coll.insert({key: ['some_value', 'some_value_1']})
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError, e:
    print e.dup_val
```

**EDIT**

It's a concurrent app, so check duplicates before insert might fail.

The field is an array, so it's hard to find out which one is the duplicate value.

Comment: Why not check if the key is already present first? Instead of managing your flow through exceptions?

Comment: @InbarRose Sometime the key may be not present when checking, but then inserted by another process/thread immediately...

Comment: That is a totally valid concern (you should explain this in your question). Also, why can't you just access the db using the key you were intending to use originally? the `DuplicateKeyError` means that key is the same, so you already have the key, then you can just access it's value.

Comment: @InbarRose sorry I didn't post the actual case at first. I've made some clarification there.

Answer (score 7):

In dev version of `pymongo` (2.7) you can check with `error_document` property:

```
try:
    db.coll.insert({name: 'some_value'})
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError, e:
    print e.error_document
```

As far as I know, in 2.6 and earlier versions, all info except error `msg` and `code` is discarded.

Comment: Oops, I hope they bring that to stable release asap. Would you like to share a link about that feature?

Comment: @neuront no docs for unstable version, so the only link [is source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/c0614bae1b82dc1b304bf3242e2130e5f52f72ac/pymongo/errors.py#L60)

Comment: Note: In pymongo (3.0+), you can only print `e.message`, unfortunately.