# python 3.6 mongoengine cannot catch exception

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mongoengine, pymongo-3.x

I have a django 1.9 project and am using mongoengine to connect to mongodb instance.

I have a model as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import * 
class Employee(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
```

A test class:

```
import web.models as models
class test:

    '''Test the accessibility of the business class'''
    def testBusiness():
        employee = models.Employee.objects.create(
            email="pedro.kong@company.com",
            first_name="Pedro",
            last_name="Kong"
        )
        try:
            employee.save()
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError as e:
            return "Error"
        return "Business Tested"
```

The problem is that i cannot catch the `DuplicateKeyError` execption:

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: rockynode.employee.$email_1  dup key: { : "pedro.kong@company.com" }
```

I tried with global try except but it still crashes the code with a `DuplicateKeyError` exception:

```
try:
    employee.save()
except:
    return "Error"
return "Business Tested"
```

For info am using the following dependencies:

> Django==1.9.7 
>   mongoengine==0.10.6
>   pymongo==3.2.2

Reff:[get-the-duplicate-value-on-duplicatekeyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395913/get-the-duplicate-value-on-duplicatekeyerror)

Any help would be highly appreciable.Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw yourself in the docs, `create` returns a saved document, so if you use it

- you don't have to save it a second time
- you must catch save exceptions in there

  ```
  try:
      employee = models.Employee.objects.create(
          email="pedro.kong@company.com",
          first_name="Pedro",
          last_name="Kong"
      )
  except Exception as e:
      return "Error \n %s" % (e)
  return "Business Tested"
  ```

or if you don't use create but save in a separate statement:

```
    employee = models.Employee(
        email="pedro.kong@company.com",
        first_name="Pedro",
        last_name="Kong"
    )
    try:
        employee.save()
    except Exception as e:
        return "Error \n %s" % (e)
    return "Business Tested"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got to solve the issue.

The `try except` was not working since the `DuplicateKeyError exception` was not being triggered from the `save()`  method but instead from the `create()` method.

Quoting from the documentation:[create()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=create#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.create) :

> Create new object. Returns the saved object instance.

The code section in the `def create()` in the mongoengine code: Reff: [Monogoengine code](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset/base.py) shows clearly that the `create()` function calls the `save()` function:

## Extract from mongoengine code:

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
        """Create new object. Returns the saved object instance.
        .. versionadded:: 0.4
        """
        return self._document(**kwargs).save()
```

Hence my `try` blocks must be enclose the `create()` method like follows:

```
 try:
            employee = models.Employee.objects.create(
                email="pedro.kong@company.com",
                first_name="Pedro",
                last_name="Kong"
            )
            employee.save()
        except Exception as e:
            return "Error \n %s" % (e)
        return "Business Tested"
```